# Sequelize options.nest in query() method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a raw query like

```
squelize.query(
   `select "order".id, "orderCustomer".id as "orderCustomer.id", "orderCustomer".forename as "orderCustomer.forename" 
    from orders as "order"
    join customers as "orderCustomer" on "orderCustomer".id = "order"."orderCustomerId"
    where "orderCustomer".forename ilike '%petra%';`,
{
    type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT, 
    model: order,
    nest: true,
    mapToModel: true
})
```

When I query this in `psql` I get a correct result set:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]----------+------
id                     | 383
orderCustomer.id       | 446
orderCustomer.forename | Petra
-[ RECORD 2 ]----------+------
id                     | 419
orderCustomer.id       | 9
orderCustomer.forename | Petra
```

The problem is, that Sequelize is apparently not able to form this into an Array of the kind

```
[
 {
   id: 383,
   orderCustomer: {
      id: 446,
      forename: 'Petra'
   }
 },
   ...
]
```

Instead I get something like this:

```
[
 {
   id: 383,
   'orderCustomer.id': 446,
   'orderCustomer.forename': 'Petra'
 },
   ...
]
```

Do I need to `include` the customer-model in the query's option-object?

### UPDATE

I logged the result of my query. There is this property `_options` on all of the returned order-instances:

```
_options:{ 
   isNewRecord: false,
   _schema: null,
   _schemaDelimiter: '',
   raw: true, // <--------- possible cause?
   attributes: undefined 
}
```

Somehow, I cannot set `options.raw` to `false` on my query definition! Maybe that is the reason why …

> …sequelize will not try to format the results of the query, or build an instance of a model from the result (see [docs > query() > options.raw](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#instance-method-query))

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello, I am facing the same issue. Was you able to fix this problem?

Comment: @Sisir no, sorry. Haven't looked into it since then...

Answer (score 1):

I'm using your solution: nest: true and it works perfectly!

```
[err, rows] = await to(sequelize.query(query,{ replacements: { search: '%'+search+'%', limit: limit, offset: skip}, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,nest: true}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the

```
model: order,
```

this solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

It is 2021 and seems that this is still doesn't work with Sequelize `6.6.2`. Or rather I can't work out how to make the `mapToModel` work in conjunction with the nested properties.

I worked around the issue by removing the `model: MyModel, mapToModel: true,` part so that the query options look like this:

`{ type: QueryTypes.SELECT, bind: [mainAssetId], nest: true, raw: false }`

I get the object back with all the fields and nested works but it is of course not an instance of the Model. It looks like the model from data perspective so as long as you don't have methods on your model you should be fine.

You could always use something like the `class-transformer` package to transform it to the model instance.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have the models set up properly,

Why not query it using associations, instead of using a raw query.
Something like this should generate a similar result

```
Model.Order.findAll({
  where:{forename:{$iLike:'someString'}},
  attributes:[/*Columns to fetch*/]
  include:[{model:Model.Customer,attributes:[/*Columns to fetch*/]}]
});
```

Also IMO using the nest attributes, wont club across multiple rows returned.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My true query is much more complex with lots of joints and its easier for me to query it directly.
The `nest` prop should be exactly doing what I want (see http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-method-query), but I doesn't :(
Do you have an idea of a solution for my problem above?

Comment: I could code a function which transforms a `'dotted.property'` into a `dotted: {property}` myself. But I thought, maybe there is a Sequelize-way...

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and made it work this way:

```
        sequelize.query(
            `SELECT q.id, q.title, a.id AS "answers.id"
               FROM questions q
               JOIN answers a ON a.question_id = q.id`,
                model: Question,
                mapToModel: true,
                nest: true,
                raw: true,
                type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }
        )
```